# Is there a present perfect error

Tags: perfect-constructions

> Zur Situation Von Konstruktionen b/w Les Mots Ètranges is Les Trucs first 7″ on fettkakao.  well – at least a very own 45. they **have had** a split out in 2010 w/ Sex Jams and **contributed** a song to the last Fettkakao compilation that **was released** early this year.

I think it should be **either** past perfect or past simple *for both verbs*:

> They had had . . . and had contributed (past perfect)

or

> they had . . . and contributed (past simple).

I don't understand why have and contributed are present perfect as both events relate to the past. Don't you think the writer should have added **so far** or **up to now** to justify present perfect?

And if it is the reason why is **release** not present perfect, as the year is not finished?

Comment: I don't know what a 'split out' is, but if I just substitute the innocuous phrase 'dinner party' then that would make me think it should just be 'had', not 'have had' nor 'had had'.

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell us what a "split out" is.

Comment: The specific meaning of *split out* is irrelevant. Both present perfect and past perfect are perfectly valid forms here - which is most appropriate depends on additional context that we don't have. Essentially, present perfect would be more suitable if the primary "narrative time" is ***now***, but if the surrounding context is inherently set in the past, past perfect would probably be more justifiable. Having said that, it's almost never a "mistake" to use present perfect even in contexts where past perfect is justifiable.

Comment: Guys, **split** is short for **split album**.

Comment: & what's a 'split album'?

Comment: I think you can ignore this. Les Trucs is a German group, and this (like most of the internet notices about them I've seen) appears to have been written by a native speaker of German (note particularly the non-standard use of *a very own*). The writer employs the perfect construction as a German speaker would.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it addresses non-standard uses by a non-native user of English.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of editing in the changes you made in your later posting. Please be aware that you should not repost your question but **revise** it; you may accomplish this by clicking on the 'edit' link immediately beneath the tags.

Comment: @StoneyB Would there be some value though in correcting it as we might if the non-native speaker who wrote it was here asking about it?

Comment: @ColleenV I think that between them OP and CarSmack have already done so.

Comment: @StoneyB I had a the misconceived idea for some reason that closed questions would be deleted instead of just being closed to new answers. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Is there more context besides just one sentence?

If it is just this one sentence, then AmE would most likely use the past simple for both verbs (*had* and *contributed*.)

The use of past perfect for both verbs is unnecessary and not preferred if this one sentence is the only context.

The present perfect here may be a BrE usage.

If it were *since 2010* then present perfect (have had) and past simple (contributed) would be fine in AmE or BrE.

Comment: So why all the verbs are not present perfect,(have, contributed and released) I dont understand why the closest event to the present is past simple .

Comment: Is this a sentence you wrote or something you found? If it is something you found, please provide a link and paste more context. If it is a sentence you wrote, I am not sure what you are asking. You can only ask one question at a time.

Comment: @user5577 They should all be past simple: in English the present perfect is deprecated with time references which exclude the present. The perfects in your passage are a German usage.